# What does this entry on the Rocinante's pilot quick-menu mean?

Tags: spaceship, the-expanse-2015, easter-egg

In Season 6 Episode 3 of The Expanse, during the battle scene, we see the "PILOT - QUICK MENU" menu on the display Holden is examining:

[image: DONKEYBALLS53]

It has mostly meaningful entries (e.g. REP FLIGHT, DOWNLINK LEAD, RELAY, SLOW RUN, GRAV ASSIST), some less meaningful ones (A552_B or whatever), and then on the bottom of the menu, we have the entry DONKEYBALLS3.

I'm assuming it's some sort of easter egg... but what does it mean?

Comment: Other interesting entries: `KAMAL_ALPHA` and `NOBINGO`.

Answer (score 23):

It's a reference to something in episode [1.07 "Windmills"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3983524/?ref_=ttep_ep7).

From [Bonus View](https://www.highdefdigest.com/blog/expanse-107-recap/):

> Suspecting that Fred Johnson may have placed a secret transmitter on
> board the ship to keep tabs on them, Amos goes to check it out.
> Instead, he finds a stowaway. It’s Kenzo, the corporate spy from Tycho
> Station. He admits to being a corporate spy, and says that he hitched
> a ride because things were getting too hot for him on Tycho and he
> needed to get out of there before Johnson caught him. (He conveniently
> leaves out the part about working for the U.N.) He claims that the
> signal he transmitted was a message to friends to pick him up at Eros
> Station, which is technically where the Rocinante’s flight plan says
> they’re heading. Holden and the others are inclined to distrust
> anything he says, and lock him in an airlock for safe keeping until
> they figure out what to do with him. Amos makes no bones about telling
> him that they’ll most likely eject him into space.
>
> As feared, a Martian Navy vessel flags the Rocinante for inspection
> and sends a shuttle with a boarding party. Kenzo begs to be let out of
> the airlock and insists that he can help. He warns Holden that as soon
> as the Martians set foot inside the ship, they’ll recognize the
> interior as one of their own vessels, but says he knows a way to
> convince them to turn around before boarding. After much pleading,
> Holden agrees to let him come back to the bridge.
>
> Kenzo’s plan is this: Rather than continue pretending to be a simple
> gas freighter, the crew should pretend to be a Martian black ops unit
> pretending to be a simple gas freighter. Apparently, Martians send
> undercover vessels like that all through the system. Each ship has a
> code book that contains a secret pass phrase that will identify it to
> other Martian ships. This jibes with something Alex remembers about
> his time as a Martian Navy pilot. During one mission, his ship was set
> to board another vessel until hearing the phrase “**donkey balls**,” at
> which point his captain immediately backed off without explanation.
>
> Holden and crew search the bridge until they find a locked safe that
> must contain the code book. As the Martian shuttle approaches, they
> race against time to break into the safe while Alex jabbers on the
> comms to stall the boarding party with friendly patter.
>
> Expecting that plan to fail, Amos grabs a rifle and heads down to the
> airlock for a “Plan B,” which will be to shoot the hell out of any
> Martians who try to board. Holden says that’s a terrible idea that
> will only get them all killed and orders him to stand down, but Amos
> doesn’t recognize his authority to make him do anything.
>
> Finally, just as the Martians are on the verge of entering the ship,
> Naomi gets the safe open and gives Alex the code book. The pass phrase
> contains three words: “ubiquitous,” “mendacious” and “polyglottal.”
> Alex struggles for a moment to figure out how to work those words into
> a sentence, but then just blurts them out. He throws in a “**donkey
> balls**” too for good measure. After pausing for a beat, the Martians
> withdraw.

Youtube has a [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6Ato2GhU-o).